# Eager loading with relations causes touch option not to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When using `includes` to eager load an active record, the updated_at does not get updated.

Simplified code:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments,
           foreign_key: 'my_model_id',
           dependent: :destroy,
           inverse_of: :my_model

end

class Comments < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :my_model, foreign_key: :my_model_id,
                        inverse_of: :comments,
                        touch: true
end
```

```
model = MyModel.includes(comments: :user).find_by!(my_id: 111)
params = {"comments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"2", "name"=>"aaa"}}
model.update(params)
# model.updated_at DOES NOT get updated.
```

```
model = MyModel.find_by!(my_id: 111)
params = {"comments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"2", "name"=>"aaa"}}
model.update(params)
# model.updated_at DOES get updated.
```

Why would the `touch` option not work when eager loading?

Comment: `inverse_of: :my_model_id` is wrong. It should be the name of the inverse assocation - but its not actually needed if it can be automatically derived. The foreign key option here is also totally superflous.

Comment: @max I fixed the inverse of the example above.  The code above is meant to be a simplified version, and I agree you don't need the foreign key based on how it is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, we should avoid `includes` when we need the touch option to work correctly on the parent.   See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/47501) for a more detailed answer.